# Pure strategy Nash Equilibria draw

Tags: game-theory, nash-equilibrium

Consider the game below.

[image]

The goal is to find all pure strategy Nash Equilibria. It's clear to me that D/L results in a Nash Equilibria. However, it's not clear whether or not U/R does the same.

If Player B chooses R, the best response of Player A is U. However, if Player A chooses U, the best response of Player B is either L or R. It's a draw for Player B. Does it still result in a Nash Equilibria?

**Update**

Additionally, choice L is a dominant strategy for Player B. So, does it make sense talking about Nash Equilibrium for D/R?

Comment: Another similar question is whether $L$ dominates $R$ (weakly yes, strictly no).  Player B's best strategy is to destroy the $R$ option and let Player A see this

Comment: I did not realize the dominant strategy L for Player B. Thanks for pointing that out!

Answer (score 0):

Everywhere I have seen it defined (*Game Theory* by Fudenberg and Tirole, Wikipedia), the definition of a Nash equilibrium allows for equality, so $(U,R)$ is a Nash equilibrium according to these sources.

However, $(U,R)$ is not a *strict* Nash equilibrium.